# Using Solve to find analytical solution

Tags: equation-solving

I'm at Day 1 of using *Mathematica* and I'm having trouble understanding why `Solve` behaves in certain ways. I'm considering the following equations:

```
EQ1 =  y^(-1 + a) - (c - y)^(-1 + a)  == 0
EQ2 =  b*y^(-1 + a) - (c - y)^(-1 + a)  == 0
```

and don't understand why `Solve[EQ1,y]` successfully solves for `y` but `Solve[EQ2, y]` fails. Certainly the values taken by `{a,b,c}` matter here, but I'm not sure how adding `b` makes the task impossible, given that I'm not making any assumptions about `a` and still getting a solution for `Solve[EQ1, y]`.

Finally, why does `Solve[{EQ1, a > 1}, y]` fail as well?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Capital letters can be reserved variables (i.e I, C) ... `K::usage "K is a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum."` ... this may be part of your problem

Comment: @Young Good to know, thanks for the suggestion - just changed K to c and am experiencing same issues.

Comment: Complicated functions sometimes don't have closed form analytical functions that can be found by `Mathematica`. Why the last one fails to solve is strange though.

Comment: Interestingly, `Reduce` doesn't solve any of the formulas, not even `EQ1`.

Comment: If you make the slight change of replacing both -1+a with aminus1 then solve is happy to solve both of them

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple work around exists and works well.

Comment: @Bill What version of Mma?  I'm not seeing the behavior you describe.  Mma 11 fails to compute `Solve[b*y^(a - 1) == (c - y)^(a - 1), y]`.

Comment: @Alan $VersionNumber==10.1 I am sorry. I think perhaps I was not clear. I meant for you to replace all of the "(-1+a)" with a new variable "aminus1", or Z, or to Solve[b*y^(-1+a)==(c-y)^(-1+a)/.(-1+a)->aminus1, y], or any simple variable.

Comment: @Feyre I disagree. The question is not due to a simple mistake. Additionally, the workaround is simple when you know it, but it had certainly not occurred to me. Finally, I'd say that this may help future visitors, at least in that it provides them an extra trick to try on gnarly problems.

Comment: @Bill I wonder if you'd be willing to turn your comment into an answer, at least for the sake of keeping record of it.

Comment: @Feyre I agree with Marco. The existence of a workaround is not grounds for closing. Also an answer from someone who understands *why* Solve behaves this way would be very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes if you simplify a problem, without changing the essence of the problem, you can get Solve or Reduce to much more quickly find a solution, or in this case to find a solution at all.

This tactic typically applies when an expression is used more than once and consists of one or more variables and or constants, but none of those variables are ever used outside those expressions and the problem would simpler, but effectively unchanged if those expressions were replaced by a single new variable.

When this trick applies, particularly for gnarly multivariate problems, this can be a powerful trick and can sometimes speed up the solution by orders of magnitude.

In this problem, since the variable a always appears as (-1+a), I tried replacing that with a simple variable, call it Z. Then

```
{Solve[y^Z - (c - y)^Z == 0, y], Solve[b*y^Z - (c - y)^Z == 0, y]}
```

instantly returns solutions for both, with the usual warning that Solve will sometimes use an inverse function.

But even this doesn't seem to be enough to enable Reduce to find all solutions in any reasonable amount of time.

Comment: It seems like it should be possible to look for such simplifications automatically, which would make a neat wrapper for `Solve`

Comment: Thanks @Bill ! The equations I posted here were actually much simpler versions of the ones I initially encountered problems with. Using multiple substitution tricks like you proposed made it work.